# Operators defined only one way - C++

Tags: c++, operators, operator-overloading

I've created a class of complex numbers, defined operations and some functions like arg, modulus etc. I've also defined the imaginary unit *i* as constant in a namespace. The problem is that `z = i + 2` doesn't return any error and work correctly but the compiler doesn't accept the line `z = 2 + i` saying that the operand is invalid between `int` and `const complex`.

What should I do to get the operation defined both ways?

Comment: Crystal ball telling me that you've fallen into the trap of making all of your operators member functions when they can be free functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should implement either a conversion between integer and complex number or define both operators:

```
complex operator+(int a, const complex& b)
```

and

```
complex operator+(const complex& a, int b)
```

Comment: When I add the 1st function, I've got `overloaded 'operator+' must be unary or binary operator (has 3 parameters)` error

Comment: @user2145816, Put it outside of the class. Every non-static member function's first parameter is a pointer to the object.

Comment: @user2145816 place this outside of your class definition, otherwise you add an implicit first parameter `this` of type complex.

Answer (score 3):

You should overload `complex operator+(int lhs, const complex& rhs);` for your class.  Make this a `friend` function so you pass in both parameters.

Comment: You don't need `friend` declarations if you define `+=`, etc. as member functions and use them to implement `+`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to providing real and complex overloads for your operators:  If you give your `complex` class a conversion constructor (a constructor that isn't marked `explicit` and can take a single parameter), then it can implicitly convert real numbers to complex numbers:

```
class complex
{
public:
    complex(double real, double imag = 0) : real_(real), imag_(imag) {}
    double real() const { return real_; }
    double imag() const { return imag_; }
private:
    double real_;
    double imag_;
};
```

Then you can define `operator+` as taking two `complex` parameters, and the compiler will convert the `int` to `complex` for you:

```
complex operator+(const complex& a, const complex& b)
{
    return complex(a.real() + b.real(), a.imag() + b.imag());
}
```

Now, when the compiler encounters this code, it will recognize that a `complex, complex` overload for `operator+` exists and that `2` can be implicitly converted to `complex`:

```
z = 2 + i;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of overloading operators for classes: as member functions and as... well, non-member functions. The first ones are created when there is an object of the class (the `Complex` class, in this case) at the left of the operator (`+` in this case). Non-member functions are used for those cases in which the above does not happen. Both operands are specified in this case, and the overloaded operator itself is only accidentally (sometimes) created inside the class with friend access (in fact, it is not needed if you won't access private members. Another reason to have it inside the class is that this way the operators of a given class are in the same place).

```
class Complex {
public:
    // more things...

    Complex operator+(int i);                               // cx + 1
    friend Complex operator+(int i, const Complex &cx);     // 1 + cx

    // more things...
};

Complex Complex::operator+(int i)
{
    Complex complexCopy( *this );
    complexCopy.sum( i );

    return complexCopy;
}

Complex operator+(int i, const Complex &cx)
{
     Complex complexCopy( cx );
     complexCopy.sum( i );

     return complexCopy;
}
```

Remember that you'll need to have the copy constructor overloaded, in case you alloc any resource in the constructor.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The non-member versions do not actually have to be friends.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to handle operator overloading of `+` is to start with `+=`.

```
class complex {
  double real
  double imag;
  complex& operator+=( complex const& other ) {
    real += other.real;
    imag += other.imag;
    return *this;
  }
  complex& operator+=( double other ) {
    real += other.real;
    return *this;
  }
};
```

then write the non-member operators to use the above member operator:

```
inline complex operator+( complex left, double right ) {
  return left+=right;
}
inline complex operator+( double left, complex right ) {
  return right+=left;
}
inline complex operator+( complex left, complex const& right ) {
  return left+=right;
}
```

note that I took at least one `complex` argument by value -- given that I'm returning a `complex` number, I might as well.

A nice thing about this plan is that the binary operators are real boilerplate, with the work being done in the member `+=` operator.

In C++11 you can go a step further, and auto-write all of the above operators, where it extracts valid types based on the various overloads of `operator+=`.  But this is only worth it if you are writing a lot of classes that overload `+`.